# Xamarin UI tests succeed on emulator but fail on App Center due to a TaskCancelledException (request time-out)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest, visual-studio-app-center-test

I'm having a problem in running Xamarin UI tests on AppCenter. There's `Setup` and `TearDown` methods that are supposed to run before and after each test respectively. During setting up and tearing down, I send a request to our server to satisfy the test conditions for that test case. Whenever we run these tests on our Android device emulator, it runs smoothly; however, when the same tests run on app center, they give out an exception that indicates that the request timed-out; exception type is essentially `TaskCancelledException`. Since `Setup` and `TearDown` methods cannot be marked `async` in Xamarin UI tests, I just wait for the task to complete using `Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run` (GitHub repo: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext). I would've thought it's an issue in that repo if it failed to run on my Android emulator. I would've thought it's an issue on our servers if the run on the emulator wasn't pointed to the servers. But since it's pointed to our servers (not a local environment), and since it runs smoothly on my Android emulator, I hereby believe the issue is on Microsoft's app center test cloud.

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Add time out

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```